# Google Charts - Pie chart with sub category

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am facing some problem in displaying data in the pie chart.

I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate my issue.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6M2sH/14/)

I am providing the below data:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year','Positive','Negative','Neutral','Comments','Score'],
      [ '2010', 74, 26,49,'bad',12345],
      [ '2011', 50, 50,13, 'good',78456],
      [ '2012', 80, 20,56, 'good',56897],
      [ '2013', 40, 60,26, 'good',25789],
      [ '2014', 70, 30,60, 'bad',124536],

    ]);
```

**Question 1**

If you look at the jsfiddle, the combo chart (below pie chart) is perfectly displaying, but the pie chart is not displaying the values properly. So is it that the pie chart can display values only from 1 column ? Because even if i pass

```
'view': {'columns': [0,1,2,3]}
```

it still takes the value only from column 1.

**Question2**

From the dropdown, if i select a year, say 2011, still then the pie chart shows value only from column 1. But the combo chart acts fine.

Am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Why are you trying to draw in a pie chart? The pie chart is meant to show the static percentage of a different values (e.g. percentage of children/adult/elderly people in 2011). But you have here dynamic data (the data changed over time), so I'd suggest to draw Line chart of Area chart instead of Pie Chart. Alternatively you can use a pie chart only when the year is selected and show the values only from that year (if that's what you want to show)

Comment: Thanks @RuslanBes. Hmm, i guess no point showing the pie chart in scenario 1. Now, about my question 2, i want to do what you suggested but even that's not working.  So i need to pass on the data in a different way ?

Comment: For scenario 2 my guess is that you have to create two dataSources (one for each chart) and manage them separately. But this is not a simple task task and requires some js/jquery programming.

Comment: Cool..I can write logics to do that. Only wanted to know if there is any default way of doing that...Thanks.

Comment: PieCharts will only use two columns: one for slice labels and one for values.  You have to put your data in this format for the PieChart in order to get what you want.  Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6M2sH/15/

Answer (score 1):

You're using view wrong. Here's a fiddle that does it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xhdn3/

And the code:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0,2]);
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(view, options);
```